# Strange behavior of TabLayout with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I'd like to have a material look of my app, and I achieve this on devices < Android version 5.0:

[image]

But if I run app on devices >= Android 5.0 I get this:
[image]

I am using fragment for pager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomPagerTextStyle" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

and details fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.socialproof.channelinfo.view.activity.WorkActivity">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

              ....

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton
   ... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: just delete row    `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and that small bottom toolbar will disappear